# Unsuccessful Parsing

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

The following parser is returning me Null value.
Can anyone help me out..

```
-(IBAction)search:(id)sender
{
    NSString *webserviceURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Delhi&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyCGeIN7gCxU8baq3e5eL0DU3_JHeWyKzic"];
    NSURL *finalURl = [NSURL URLWithString:webserviceURL];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:finalURl];
    NSString *data1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
    NSLog(@"Result is :%@", data1);
    NSError * error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:& error];

    NSLog(@"Result is :%@", json);
}
```

Comment: What does the `error` say, and what does `data` say.

Comment: @dreamlax wait i am updating whole function....

Comment: Sahil,Try explaining the context of what you are actually trying to achieve by posting your related code completely in ordered to get answered.

Comment: I think the response from the target URL is XML instead of JSON (just tried in the browser).Do you know that the url returns JSON for sure?

Comment: @Hariprasad actually i am passing the google url which is going to show the location on the map.This is then parsed in order to view the location, but some how it is not parsing the location.

Comment: Try to use XML Parser this is sml and you parse json. this is not possible.

Comment: k i m updating the url please check it out.

Comment: @sahildhiman used my code solve your requirement.

Comment: The response from the server is ok and it is XML (The scope of the above method).You have to think about how to pass it to the map(or any custom view that you are using) to display the location.

Comment: @Hariprasad I think above url is returning JSON values please check the url and use http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ to see the output

Comment: @DushyantSingh thanx bro it is working well...... now can u please tell me how this data is shown on the map as a location with markers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code.

```
NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Delhi&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyCGeIN7gCxU8baq3e5eL0DU3_JHeWyKzic"];

NSData * data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSError * error;
NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:& error];

NSLog(@"Result is :%@", json);


NSArray * responseArr = json[@"results"];

for(NSDictionary * dict in responseArr)
{
        [firstArray addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"firstkey"]];
        [secondArray addObject:[dict valueForKey:@"secondkey"]];    
}

    NSLog(@"%@",firstArray);
    NSLog(@"%@",secondArray);
```

and after getting your data in array do what you want

use this code as it is and replace thius code with your code this will get your json response.

Comment: thanx jitender it is working well.....now can u please tell me how this data is shown on the map as a location with markers.

Comment: now can u please tell me how this data is shown on the map as a location with markers.

Comment: @jitender help me in the above question....

Comment: get all your keys in array or string whtever you want using ObjcetForKey and then locate in map.

Comment: can u please show me through coding...

Comment: @jitender i am getting both the arrays with null value.